# JPA 2.0 / Application managed / EntityManager null

Tags: java, jpa, dependency-injection, null, entitymanager

I am trying to build a sample application in pure jee7. I'm stuck with the DAO part:

When i use:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPu");
```

Emf is not null and i can persist/find etc etc...

When i try to use dependency injection like:

```
@Singleton
public class MyDAOClass{

@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "myPu")
EntityManagerFactory emf;
}
```

emf is null. I use Wildfly 8. I am using the jee7 doc from oracle and i dont find where i did my mistake.

my persistence.xml is well placed. Wildfly detects it when it starts...

PU looks like:

```
<persistence-unit name="plcmanagerPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>fr.digitalautomation.entity.ui.PLCBackgroundView</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/plcmanager"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root135"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Some advise would be very appreciated.

Thx you !

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<persistence-unit name="myPu">
```

Comment: It was a mistake. My PU name match in my program. Thx you for your interest.